# Creative Commons ShareALike LaTeX template

Tags: copyright, creative-commons

I am writing a book in LaTeX. I am using a LaTeX template that has a Creative Commons NonCommercial ShareALike license ([CC BY-NC-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)).

I would like my ebook (pdf and epub formats) to have the Creative Commons NonCommercial NonDerivatives ([CC BY-NC-ND 4.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/)).

If the license transfers itself from the template to the compiled pdf, [this change of license seems incompatible](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#can-i-combine-material-under-different-creative-commons-licenses-in-my-work).

But, I presume this is possible, because my ebook is an *original work* that only *uses* the template mentionate above. I am not redistributing the template.

Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably correct, a document is not normally a derived work of a document template.

In some cases a template includes significant text which is always or optionally included in the document. In such cases the document might be a derived work.

But in the more usual case where the template merely provides formats such as font types and sizes, document margins, header styles, and the like, the document would not be a derivative work, and there would be no obligation to place the document under the same or a compatible license.